# Django password_change doesn't work

Tags: django

I have trouble implementing password_change in django.

Here is my code :

```
url('^password-change/$',password_change,{'post_change_redirect': 
'users:password_change_done'},name='password_change'),

url('^password- change/done/',password_change_done,name='users_password_change_done'),
```

The html code is :

```
<h1>Change Password</h1>

<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

<input type="submit" value="Change password">
</form>
```

The error that I get is :

NoReverseMatch at /users/password-change/

Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I have looked at other posts that deal with similar issues but I have not been able to fix my code based on those answers.

Comment: did you notice that you have a extra space in: "url('^password- change/done/'.....". if that is not your problem I guess that in your views.py you are trying to reverse "password_change_done", but the name of the url is "users_password_change_done". Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this in urls.py

```
url('^password-change/$', password_change, {'post_change_redirect': 
'users:users_password_change_done'}, name='password_change'),

url('^password-change/done/$', password_change_done, name='users_password_change_done'),
```

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote cuz I dont have enough reputation! 
Thank you that worked!